# Firefox Unable to Handle %2b in Page Links

Tags: html, firefox, urlencode

I noticed an issue where with the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>UrlEncode Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://example.com/Process.php?OrderID=y%2bog%3d">Process</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Instead of replacing **%2b** with **+**, Firefox does so with a space instead so that clicking on the link tries to navigate to "http://example.com/Process.php?OrderID=y og=" instead of "http://example.com/Process.php?OrderID=y+og=".  IE and Chrome has no problems with this at all; just Firefox.  Has anybody else encountered this and was able to workaround it?

Answer (score 0):

You're running into an issue with URL Encoding.

In your case, I would suggest forming the url like this:

> http://example.com/Process.php?OrderID=y+bog%3d

Since it seems as if you intend to actually use the "+" symbol in that fashion.  There's no problem with having a "+" symbol in your url.

Comment: The problem is that the URL may be generated by PHP's urlencode(), ASP.NET's HttpUtility.UrlEncode() or Python's urllib.quote(), so "+" in the original string will become "%2b".

Answer (score 0):

So I saved the code you offered in a local HTML file, opened it in Firefox 3.5 (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5), hovered the link (saw "y+og" in the status bar), clicked it and the location bar contained `http://example.com/Process.php?OrderID=y%2bog%3d`. Can you actually reproduce the problem with your example? What Firefox version on what OS? Exact steps to reproduce?

Comment: The steps I use are to save a local file using the HTML above and open it in Firefox 3.5 on Windows Vista.

Comment: And then? What did you see when hovering the link? When clicking it? My guess is that it could be related to the regional settings and/or character encoding settings in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use "+" in stead of %2b. But here tracking will be done on %2b. Since few browser will convert this character in to encoding and Leeds to %2b. Please be having track with this kind.

And also its depend on which kind of mailing software you are using at.

Remedy is to create the link by is using "+" in it.

Nithan urs / 
QA Department - Email Marketing.